# How to do search in asp.net mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

iam using mvc3,i have empty search form in that am using only textbox with search button,if user search for data and click search button,then it has to show the result which is taken from index view.
Here is my controller action

```
     public ActionResult Search(string searchString)
    {
        var certificate = from s in db.certificate_mst
                       select s;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            certificate = certificate.Where(s => s.CertificateNo.Contains(searchString));

        }
        return View(certificate);
    }
```

and my view code is

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Search","certificate1",FormMethod.Get))
{
<p><b>CertificateNo</b>:@Html.TextBox("searchString")
<input type="submit" value="search" />
```

By using this code,searching is working but am getting all the data which i have in my view before searching,i need to have empty form before click search button and only after i click search it has to show result.

Answer (score 3):

Simply check for empty string before retrieving certificates

```
public ActionResult Search(string searchString)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
         //Return empty viewModel
         return View();
    }

    var certificate = db.certificate_mst.Where(s => s.CertificateNo.Contains(searchString));
    return View(certificate);
}
```

also check out a blog post I wrote on a search extension method for IQueryable that should be helpful to you

<s>http://www.ninjanye.co.uk/2013/03/c-generic-search-extension-method-for.html</s>

http://jnye.co/Posts/6/c%23-generic-search-extension-method-for-iqueryable

using the extension method your code becomes...

```
var certificate = db.certificate_mst.Search(s => s.CertificateNo, searchString));
```

The preferred method would be to split your view into a get and post action as follows.  This allows you to return all results should an empty string be posted:

```
public ActionResult Search()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(string searchString)
{
    var certificate = db.certificate_mst.Where(s => s.CertificateNo.Contains(searchString));
    //OR
    //var certificate = db.certificate_mst.Search(s => s.CertificateNo, searchString));
    return View(certificate);        
}
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable reply,this is very helpful to me.i need another help,i have a column in which i need to generate id values automatically based on some criteria but not identity,can you help me which method to follow with sample code

Comment: Hi @sanjay1234, yours search request is a bit too ambiguous for me to give you a meaningful answer.  I'd suggest you create a new question with as much detail as possible, which I'll keep an eye out for.  Please accept this answer if you believe it has answered your question

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a view model for your search screen in case you need to add more filtering items later in your search. Then you won't have a parameter for each search filter, just one, namely your view model. The way that you currently have it now also works, below is just an alternative method.

A view model might look like this:

```
public class SearchViewModel
{
     public string SearchString { get; set; }

     // Other filter items if you need anything else
}
```

Your controller's action methods

```
public ActionResult Search()
{
     SearchViewModel viewModel = new SearchViewModel();

     return View(viewModel);
}
```

Remove your data access from your controller and work through a service layer or repository:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(SearchViewModel viewModel)
{
     // Check for null viewModel

     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          // A possible failed validation is when no search string was entered,
          // and then you don't want to do any database calls.
          // Just pass back the view model and let the view handle the displaying of errors

          return View(viewModel);
     }

     // If validation succeeds now you can use your search string to retrieve data
     searchService.Search(viewModel.SearchString);

     // Do what else you need to do and the return the correct view

     return View();
}
```

And your search view can look like this:

```
@model YourProject.ViewModels.Searches.SearchViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
     @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SearchString)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SearchString)

     <button id="searchButton" type="submit">Search</button>
}
```

I hope this makes more sense now.